# Convert a fraction to whole number

Tags: decimal-expansion

Lets say that there are a few fractions:

```
x = 0.584592145015
y = 0.443242244323
```

How do one convert these fractions to `whole` numbers? That is:

```
xw = 584592145015
yw = 443242244323
```

The point is that the fraction can be upto any amount of precision. Is there a generalized way to determine what power of 10 to multiply with the fraction to convert it to a whole number?

Thanks.

Comment: who and why down voted?

Answer (score 2):

You can think about it this way: Each power of $10$ "moves" the decimal point one place to the right. For example: 
$$0.00002\times10^5=2$$
For the two numbers in your problem, you can multiply them by $10^{12}$ to get whole numbers, since there are $12$ digits past the decimal point in each number.

Comment: So we can generalize that multiplying with 10^n (where n = number of digits after 0) will give the whole number?

Comment: Right. You should try a few examples on your calculator to see that it works.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Appreciated.

Comment: It’s even simpler than that. Given a number $x$, and an integer $d$, you can form the approximation of $x$ as a fraction $$x\approx\frac{\lfloor dx \rfloor}{d}$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ just rounds down to an integer.

Comment: @MPW I was answering "is there a generalized way to determine what power of 10 to multiply with the fraction to convert it to a whole number?"

Comment: Yes, +1 for your answer. I was commenting that there is a more general interpretation.